# Cannot restart mysql client on Windows 10

Tags: mysql

I am having issues restarting the MySQL client. I have tried to restart the client  under services.msc and the command line but it doesn't restart. The errors that I'm getting are:

```
# services.msc
The SQL Service on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs.

# command line
The SQL Service is starting.
The SQL Service could not be started.
The Service did not report an error.
More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 3534
```

I've tried changing the properties to use the Local System account as per some suggestions, but that does not solve the issue either.

Prior to restarting my client, I made some changes to the my.ini file. I am just wondering if making any changes to the config file would result in this issue. Also, how would I be able to restore a copy of the default my.ini file so I can replace it with the existing.

Thank you.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? If older than 5.7.18, you can just copy the default-my.ini file. They removed it in 5.7.18.

Comment: @drakin8564 I'm using MySQL 8.0. Are there any other ways to get a default ini file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the contents of the my.ini from a fresh install of MySQL 8.0 that I happened to have:

[Default MySQL80 my.ini](https://pastebin.com/wjHMNR20)

Snippet:

```
# Other default tuning values
# MySQL Server Instance Configuration File
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Generated by the MySQL Server Instance Configuration Wizard
#
#
# Installation Instructions
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# On Linux you can copy this file to /etc/my.cnf to set global options,
# mysql-data-dir/my.cnf to set server-specific options
# (@localstatedir@ for this installation) or to
# ~/.my.cnf to set user-specific options.
```